# Ruby - Creating a file in memory

Tags: ruby, csv, io

Is there anyway to write the following code in Ruby without writing the file to disk?

```
temp_file = 'path/to/file.csv'
users = [a@b.c, c@b.a]

CSV.open(temp_file, "w") do |csv|
  csv << data_for_report
end

Reports.sendreport users temp_file

File.delete(temp_file)
```

The Reports.sendreport attaches a file and sends an email, so it needs to be a file...

Comment: So you want a string of comma separated values? Do you need the csv at that point? Could you join your columns with commas, and your rows with newlines?

Comment: Ohh, the sendreport function sends a mail with a csv-file attached. So I really need it to be a file...

Comment: Are you saying the sendreport method reads the file from disk?

Comment: Correct.. It reads a file from disc and attaches it to an email. The question now is if there is anyway to save the file, as a file, in memory.

Comment: If you can't change `Reports`, then you probably are doing it the right way. It's probably more trouble than it's worth to get a section of memory to pretend it's a disk so `Reports` can read from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the mmap gems. If the library *only* takes a filename, that's your option.

If it can accept a file-like object, however, you can use a StringIO.

You might consider changing whatever `Reports` is, making it more general-purpose. It depends on what it's using to create its mail message–this might be trivial.

Comment: I will look into StringIO, think that might be what I am looking for... Reports.sendreport is really just my own wrapper on the gmail gem, so I am not really sure if i need a real if or if StringIO will work.

Answer (score 21):

You could use [`Tempfile`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html).
`Tempfile` writes the file to disc, so it does not fit your request.

But I think Tempfile provides some features you need:

> When a Tempfile object is garbage collected, or when the Ruby interpreter exits, its associated temporary file is automatically deleted.

Example:

```
require 'tempfile'
require 'csv'

data_for_report = [1,2,3,4]
temp_file = Tempfile.new('foo')

CSV.open(temp_file, "w") do |csv|
  csv << data_for_report
end
```

Comment: It is one step closer.. Thank you!

Comment: Note that it's `Tempfile`, not `TempFile`.

Comment: The link to Ruby doc is broken

Answer (score 4):

```
temp_file = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << data_for_report
end

Reports.sendreport users temp_file
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question `Is there anyway to write the following code in Ruby without writing the file to disk?` Other answers seems to be workarounds (tempfiles)

Answer (score 3):

With your current code that's not possible, if your code would use file pointers/handles instead you can do the following:

```
require 'csv'
require 'stringio'

data_for_report = [1,2,3,4]
temp_file = StringIO.new # creates a fake file as string.

CSV.new(temp_file, "w") do |csv|
  csv << data_for_report
end
```

The key problem why it isn't working for your usecase is the line `Reports.report users temp_file`

If that accepts a handle instead of a string it'll work.

See also this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110958/887836