# Ruby Mock a file with StringIO

Tags: ruby, file-io, mocking, stringio

I am trying to mock  **file read** with the help of StringIO in Ruby.
The following is my test and next to that is my method in the main class.

```
def test_get_symbols_from_StringIO_file
    s = StringIO.new("YHOO,141414")
    assert_equal(["YHOO,141414"], s.readlines)
end

def get_symbols_from_file (file_name)
  IO.readlines(file_name, ',')
end
```

I want to know if this is the way we mock the file read and also I would like to know if there is some other method to mock the method in the class rather than doing assert equal with contents.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's passing, but `get_symbols_from_file` is actually never called in the test.

Comment: @Stefan, I agree. The test above isn't worth anything since the method is never even called!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your method `get_symbols_from_file` is never called in the test. You're just testing that `StringIO#readlines` works, i.e.:

```
StringIO.new("YHOO,141414").readlines == ["YHOO,141414"] #=> true
```

If you want to use a `StringIO` instance as a placeholder for your file, you have to change your method to take a [`File`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html) instance rather than a file name:

```
def get_symbols_from_file(file)
  file.readlines(',')
end
```

Both, `File` and `StringIO` instances respond to `readlines`, so the above implementation can handle both:

```
def test_get_symbols_from_file
  s = StringIO.new("YHOO,141414")
  assert_equal(["YHOO,141414"], get_symbols_from_file(s))
end
```

This test however fails: `readlines` includes the line separator, so it returns an array with two elements `"YHOO,"` (note the comma) and `"141414"`. You are expecting an array with one element `"YHOO,141414"`.

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
def test_get_symbols_from_file
  s = StringIO.new("YHOO,141414")
  assert_equal(["YHOO", "141414"], get_symbols_from_file(s))
end

def get_symbols_from_file(file)
  file.read.split(',')
end
```

If you really want to use `IO::readlines` you could create a [`Tempfile`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html):

```
require 'tempfile'

def test_get_symbols_from_file
  Tempfile.open("foo") { |f|
    f.write "YHOO,141414"
    f.close
    assert_equal(["YHOO", "141414"], get_symbols_from_file(f.path))
  }
end
```